# dnsmasq config forwarding queries for domain.net but keeping local.domain.net queries non forwarded

Tags: dnsmasq

What would be correct config for situation where I would want to forward queries of everything under domain.net except local.domain.net? I have set my /etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf to have my local DNS servers and "search local.domain.net" and my /etc/dnsmasq.d/internal.conf has

```
server=/domain.net/192.168.100.10
server=/domain.net/192.168.100.11
```

Now when I am asking vm1.local.domain.net from my local DNS servers they always try to send the request to domain.net DNS servers. What else should I change to have the queries kept local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can try the following in `dnsmasq`'s configuration file:

```
local=/local.domain.net/
local=/#/
server=/domain.net/192.168.100.10
```

which will use local resolution for all domains other than `domain.net`.

Comment: queries outside of domain.net would stay local. In which file should I add that line you suggested?